# Django media uploads to AS3

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto, django-storage

I'm trying to upload all the Django media files (uploaded from the admin panel) to Amazon S3. So settings file look something like this :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.admin',
'tastypie',
'core',
'advertisment',
'storages',

)

  DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'xxx' 
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxx'
  AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'media'
  MEDIA_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/%s/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

and when I try to upload a file from the admin panel, i get the following error:

```
S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
```

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854095/boto-exception-s3responseerror-s3responseerror-403-forbidden) answer but still didn't help

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed [boto](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/boto), as django-storage has a dependency on boto?

Then you will have to add the following into your settings.py

```
import os

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET_NAME')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

STATIC_URL = 'http://' + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + '.s3.amazonaws.com/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'
```

Then your cache will be stored on AWS S3 itself.

I hope it helps

Note: for security reasons its a good idea to add your AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY as environment variables instead of just writing them down in setting.py directly.

Comment: Yes I do have Boto installed and I still have the same problem. After spending few hours trying to figure it out, I think the issue is when boto tries to get the bucket key. Please review my edit in the original post.

Comment: i just used this setting. i confirmed it is working for django 1.6. thanks so much!