# Not able to write file in amazon s3 with django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have given 'everyone' as all permissions in AWS s3 bucket permissions.

Ia m using django. I am able to read the files but i am not able to write it.

I am trying this

```
>>> print default_storage.connection
S3Connection:s3.amazonaws.com
>>> from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
>>> from django.core.cache import cache

>>> default_storage.exists('testkey')
True



>>> file = default_storage.open('storage_test', 'w')
>>> file.write('storage contents')
Traceback (most recent call last):


S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>FDD54
```

I have added this in settings

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXA'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='XXXXXXX'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME='testbucket'
```

I am also confused how to   django s3 knows which user to use from s3 . i am confused. The access key is for the `user_123` which i created but in permission i am not able to see that user in aws s3 dropdown

Comment: Would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854095/boto-exception-s3responseerror-s3responseerror-403-forbidden

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am also confused how to django s3 knows which user to use from s3

This is determined strictly by the Accesskey and secret key you placed in your config.

Did you give `user_123` access to S3? In the IAM console, you need to give `user_123` access to the bucket like this:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::testbucket/*", "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Don't forget to remove 'Everyone's permission to the bucket

Comment: but where is `user_123` written in that policy

Comment: The policy is attached to user_123. In the IAM console, select users->user_123->Permissions tab->"Attack User Policy" and paste the above policy in. It will apply to user_123 by virtue of being attached to user_123