# PHP: Pass variable to AWS SDK2 uploader

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am completely stuck on what I expected to be a simple problem. The following Amazon AWS SDK2 script uploads files successfully to AWS S3 when the $filepath variable is an absolute path to the file being uploaded and is defined within the script.

However, when I try to use a simple form to select a file and pass it to the AWS script as a variable, I tie myself in knots. Eg Have tried $_FILES[‘input1’][‘name’], $_FILES[‘input1’][‘tmp_name’], realpath(), file_get_contents() to get access to the full path. Also tried using javascript, but the path is then altered to ‘fakepath’ by the browser.  I clearly don’t understand something about type = “file” within the  element.

So, my question: How can I enable a user to select a file from local disk and (using the POST action??) pass the file’s path as a variable to the AWS SDK2 upload script? My simple test form is included below too.

Simple form:

```
<body>
 <form id="form1" action="SDK2_script_process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" id="input1" name="input1" />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Search" >
 </form> </body>
```

Process script(SDK2_script_process.php):

```
<?php
 //CONNECTS TO AWS V2 SDK AND UPLOADS FILE
//Literal path to aws.phar file
 require_once 'AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Guzzle\Http\EntityBody;

// Instantiate the S3 client with AWS credentials and optional desired AWS region
 $client = S3Client::factory(array(
 'key' => 'MYKEY',
 'secret' => MYSECRETKEY'
  ));

//Name of bucket on S3
 $bucket = 'mybucket';
 //Filename to be saved in S3 Bucket
 $filename = "/directoryA/directoryB/filename.extension";

//Literal filepath to file I want to save - THIS WORKS
// $filepath = '../../directory1/directory2/directory3/filename.extension';

// Filepath from simple form - DOES NOT WORK 
 $filepath = $_FILES['input1']['tmp_name'];

$result = $client->putObject(array(
 'Bucket' => $bucket,
 'Key' => $filename,
 'SourceFile' => $filepath,
 'Metadata'   => array(
        'title' => 'This is the title metadata',
        'artist' => 'This is the artist metadata'
        )
 ));

// HEAD object confirms success
$headers = $client->headObject(array(
  "Bucket" => $bucket,
  "Key" => $filename
));
//print_r($headers->toArray());

echo $result['ObjectURL'];
echo $headers['Metadata']['artist'];


?>
```

Appreciate any help, or pointers to a different way of using this SDK2 script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068311/aws-403-forbidden-when-attempting-client-side-post), I think. I should be using PostObject, not putObject.

See Aws\S3\Model\PostObject; in the [SDK docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.Model.PostObject.html).