# AWS S3 bucket Storage using python

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am trying to connect amazon s3 bucket using python as follows

```
   import boto
   from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
   from boto.s3.key import Key

   conn = S3Connection(settings.AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
   pb = conn.get_bucket(settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
```

but i am receiving the following error

```
S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
```

i followed the below link
http://www.techchorus.net/writing-python-script-send-files-amazon-s3

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: are your access keys right?

Comment: Yes key is correct i connect using "CloudBerry Explorer for Amazon S3" tool.

Comment: hmm not sure then, maybe check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854095/boto-exception-s3responseerror-s3responseerror-403-forbidden  could be something to do with "SERVER TIME"?

Comment: It is likely an  issue with access control.   If you remove the validation part of the get_bucket, does it work?   conn.get_bucket(settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, validate=False)  .

Comment: @cgseller Thank you now its connected.